# What differences are between "What's that?" and "What is it?"

Tags: meaning, pronouns, demonstrative

What do you imagine when you hear

> "What's that?"

vs.

> "What is it?"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to stress on.

In case of  "What **is** it?" - it is the "IS" that is getting stressed.

But in case of "What's **that**? "  it is the  "THAT" that is getting stressed.

Probably you understood that mild difference.

Answer (score 0):

"It" is a subjective pronoun. "That" is a demonstrative. There is a difference. In general use, something like "What is that!" would be used when there isn't a clear object. For example, if I was looking at a flock of birds and one of them was different, I would say "Look at that!" or "Look at that bird". But if we were talking about said bird, I might say "I wonder what kind of bird it is." I hope this clarifies something, if at least the usage.

Comment: Do you mean if the object is not sure by a speaker and a listener, then they use "that"? if the object is sure by both or either side, they use "it"?

Comment: This may help you. http://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2014/01/22/it-vs-that-in-grammar-conversation-english-lesson/