# "What is it?" vs "What is this?"

Tags: grammar, questions

When entertaining a young child who is learning English, I heard some people asking her

> What is it?

when pointing to her finger.

I was surprised because I always learned to ask

> What is this?

when pointing something (or *that* is there is a need to differentiate the distance, or in general separate the items).

Their rationale was that the answer will be "*it is a finger*".

**Is the question "*what is it?*" correct when pointing something?**

Bonus question: is there a (ideally - strict) grammatical rule for this case?

Note: I hoped [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80530/what-differences-are-between-whats-that-and-what-is-it) would be a duplicate but the context is different (though it implies that there is no problem with "*What is it?*")

Comment: The physical gesture of pointing itself conveys the meaning of the word **this**.  The physical gesture in combination with **this** reinforces the meaning.  Pointing + **it** is not ungrammatical.

Comment: Using *this* implies proximity. In such situations, using *it* is unnatural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no hard and fast rule for your example.

> **What is it?**

can be used for all situations.  As pointed out

> **What is this?**

may imply something which is closer, but may not. In a situation with something mysterious coming down a road towards you, you might use

> What is **that**?
> What is **this**?
> What is **it**?

and all three would be correct.  The nuance might be that "***What is this?***" might sound more curious than "***What is that?***" which may sound repulsive.  "***What is it?***" could be used either way depending on intonation.